# How to fit an Image to column width in Flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, flutter-image

I want to fit a child image to the width of the column father.

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
    Image.network("Some image url"),
    Text("Fitted image"),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suggest the following chenges

```
Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Image.network("Your image url",
          width: double.infinity, 
          fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
        ),
        Text("Fitted image"),
      ],
    )
```

Comment: Perfect, this answer is even better!

Answer (score 6):

Well, I resolved my problem using **MediaQuery**.

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
        child: Image.network("Some image url", fit: BoxFit.fill,), 
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    ),
    Text("Fitted image"),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe wrapping your Image with an Expanded Widget and give it BoxFit.fitWidth would also be useful. Or in case the times when you can't use MediaQuery.

```
     Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 5,
            child: Image.network(
              "Some Image Url",
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            ),
          ),
          Text("Fitted image"),
        ],
      ),
```

If you need to control the size of elements in the column try to wrap all your widgets inside column with expanded widget and adjust elements sizes with flex value.

Comment: Your solution is not bad, but Expand expands through the main axis, so it will grow vertically (column), it works because the image keeps his aspect ratio and grows his width also ;-)