# flutter image fit lefts space at left and right

Tags: flutter, image

I have a question about images in a flutter. I have a Column and inside of it I have an image, I need to stretch it at full width but I could not. There are a few spaces left on the left and right for the white circle at the end of the screen. Where is the wrong statement in my code?

Thanks,

```
home: Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: HexColor(primary),
    body: SafeArea(
      bottom: false,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          // Header text & Pawline image
          Row(
            ...
          ),
          // Banner image
          Row(...
          ),
          // Circle
          // TODO: Stretch circle image to the both ends
          Expanded(
            child: Image.asset(
              "assets/images/circle.png",
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

[image]

Edit: Circle image:

[image]

Comment: could you also add your image here too? I think the image has border.

Comment: Has no border but it is smaller than the screens width

Comment: could add image file here too?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fit an Image to column width in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59362886/how-to-fit-an-image-to-column-width-in-flutter)

Comment: Added @eamirho3ein, it is hard to see but it is right under the phone screen.

Answer (score 0):

you are setting an image with specific sized to smaller size, this is cause your issue. try remove the Expanded widget and set `Image's fit` to `fitWidth` and wrap other part of widget with `Expanded`, like Banner image, to avoid `RenderFlex overflowed` issue.

Comment: Sorry, still the same...

Comment: @DGulyasar try remove Expanded

Comment: Not worked without expanded, space growed

Comment: If you add other part of your widget, I may help you

Answer (score 0):

Try using `fit: BoxFit.fill`

```dart
 Image.asset(
     "assets/images/circle.png",
     fit: BoxFit.fill,
     width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
```

Comment: Did not change anything

Comment: Is there other padding widget contains around it? try providing width

Comment: +try to recheck the image including path